# Are there any Android keyboards with swipe functionality available that are more precise than the main options?

Tags: android, keyboard

I use a combination of swiping and voice input to type on Android mobile because I have hand problems and having too many presses is painful for me. But I always end up having to edit what I say because of the predictive nature of all the keyboards I've tried.

For example, somebody posts a meme of a tombstone of Internet Explorer. I tried to swipe "rip", but it always comes out as "to" because the predictive feature thinks that's more likely to be at the start of a sentence.

I'm well aware that most people are not that precise with their swiping and that is why these features work this way, but I have more attention to detail than that and it's really frustrating that my device always responds like it thinks it knows better than me. Obviously, other similar features are very annoying too.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can't test droid, but iOS will always guess *'To'* unless you double-tap for all-caps, then it will go straight for *'RIP'*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Microsoft SwiftKey (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey) and I'm quite happy with it. Just tested your use case and it let me enter 'rip' without making it 'to'. Of course, I had to make a very short break on the 'i'.